# How to change the data types for Liquibase's own tables

Tags: timestamp, oracle9i, liquibase

When running Liquibase on a database for the first time it will try to create two tables that it uses to manage its changesets.

When I run Liquibase on my Oracle9i database it tries to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE myuser.DATABASECHANGELOG (
  ID VARCHAR2(63) NOT NULL,
  AUTHOR VARCHAR2(63) NOT NULL,
  FILENAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
  DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EXECTYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  MD5SUM VARCHAR2(35),
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(255),
  COMMENTS VARCHAR2(255),
  TAG VARCHAR2(255),
  LIQUIBASE VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOG PRIMARY KEY (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME)
);
```

I get this error/exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Oracle9i doesn't have the TIMESTAMP data type (later versions of Oracle do).

Is there a way to either make Liquibase use a different data type or tell Liquibase that it's working with an earlier version of Oracle?

Or am I out of luck because Liquibase doesn't support Oracle9i?

EDIT: Oracle9i *does* have the timestamp data type but my database is running in 8i compatibility mode and that can't change unfortunately.  The question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to create the DATABASECHANGELOG table and the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table manually using the date datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE myuser.DATABASECHANGELOG (
   ID VARCHAR2(63) NOT NULL,
   AUTHOR VARCHAR2(63) NOT NULL,
   FILENAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   DATEEXECUTED DATE NOT NULL,
   ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL,
   EXECTYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
   MD5SUM VARCHAR2(35),
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(255),
   COMMENTS VARCHAR2(255),
   TAG VARCHAR2(255),
   LIQUIBASE VARCHAR2(20),
   CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOG PRIMARY KEY (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME)
);

CREATE TABLE myuser.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (
   ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
   LOCKED NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
   LOCKGRANTED DATE,
   LOCKEDBY VARCHAR2(255),
   CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

You also need to insert a record into the lock table:

```
INSERT INTO myuser.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, locked, lockgranted, lockedby) VALUES (1, 0, NULL, NULL);
```